# Формула подошвы

Tags: геометрия

Подскажите, как составить формулу подошвы тапочка. Например вот такого:

[image]

В формулу передаются параметры: длина и вероятно ширина в нескольких местах. А на выходе нужно получить массив из точек.
Нужно для 3д печати и более простого изменения параметров модели.

Для тестирования формулы можно воспользоваться https://openjscad.org/ .
Пример кода, рисующий фигуру по формуле:

```
function main() {
   var o = [];
   var flen = 26;

   for(var i=0; i < 360; i += 3) {
      o.push(cylinder({r:1, h:1}).translate([(sin(5 * i) + 5 ) * sin(i), (sin(5*i) + flen) * cos(i)])
      );
   }

   return o;
}
```

Comment: Попробуй интерполяцию кубическими сплайнами.

Comment: прикольный вопрос. это полярные координаты? предположу что помоглго бы FFT, надо бы пробовать...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нет, обычные координаты, расстояние от точки 0,0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалось построить модель через вот такую хитрую формулу, собранную методом подбора:

```
[
  (a < 180 
  ? (sin(4 * a / 1.6 + 10.9) + 6.4 ) * sin(a) * 1.0
  : (sin(5 * a / 1.33) + 1 ) * sin(a) * 0.9
 )
   +  (abs(180 - a) < 30 && a > 180 ? (210 - a) / 20 : 0)
   -  (a > 330 ? (330 - a) / 20 : 0)
  + (a > 180 ? - 3.5 : 0 )
  ,
  cos(a)
  ]
```